How do I check if the next element in ArrayList is empty or exists?
I have a 2D ArrayList for which I want to print out the names with commas if they're in the same row except for the last one. To do this I would need to check if the element before the one I am currently on is empty or exists. How do I do this?
This is my code:
List<List<String>> lists = new ArrayList<>();
    
List<String> bakeryList = new ArrayList<>();
bakeryList.add("Pasta");
bakeryList.add("Garlic bread");
bakeryList.add("Donuts");
    
List<String> produceList = new ArrayList<>();
produceList.add("Tomatoes");
produceList.add("Zucchini");
produceList.add("Onions");
    
List<String> drinkList = new ArrayList<>();
drinkList.add("Soda");
drinkList.add("Water");
    
lists.add(bakeryList);
lists.add(produceList);
lists.add(drinkList);
    
for (int i = 0; i < lists.size(); i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < lists.get(i).size(); j++) {
        if (???) {
            System.out.print(lists.get(i).get(j) + ", ");
        } else {
            System.out.print(lists.get(i).get(j));
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
}


The simple way is to check if(j  < lists.get(i).size() - 1) you could skip the inner loop though, and do String.join(", ", lists.get(i)).

Could you help me out on where to use String.join exactly and what to delete? I'm kind of lost.

Help us help you - share the expected output

A more compact version to solve this (if you want each list's elements to be printed in the same line with commas) using streams would be the following:
 lists.forEach(list ->  System.out.println(list.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(", "))));


With your original loop.
for (int i = 0; i < lists.size(); i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < lists.get(i).size(); j++) {
        if (???) {
            System.out.print(lists.get(i).get(j) + ", ");
        } else {
            System.out.print(lists.get(i).get(j));
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
}

The inner loop can be replaced with String.join.
for (int i = 0; i < lists.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println( String.join(", ", lists.get(i) ) );   
}

The alternative is to replace ??? with j  < lists.get(i).size() - 1

Alternatively Use String.join() to handle comma separation automatically,
for (List<String> list : lists){
System.out.println(String.join(", ", list));
}

String.join() - this method joins the elements of the list into a single string separated by commas.
Also, this removes the need for manual checking of the last element.
Further, we can utilize java streams,
lists.stream()
.map(list -> list.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(", ")))
.forEach(System.out::println);


j < lists.get(i).size() - 1
But you could also use the String.join method.

I add this answer, just to show another way, since the answer of matt, perfectly fulfills the premise.
String out = "";
for( List<String> items : lists ) {
   for( String name : items ) {
        // to all lines we add ”, ” 
      out += name + ", ";
   }
     // we remove the last ”, ” and add the line break  
   out = out.substring( 0, out.length() -2 ) + "\n";
}
System.out.print( out );

In this way, we have the result stored in a variable.

Unless You must use Looping Constructs, a functional approach could be much concise and simpler. Just for clarity, the for(...){} Construct is replaced with a simple printData() Method.
  public static void printData(List<List<String>> objectList) {
    return objectList.stream().map( o -> { // map through outer list:
        o.remove(o.size() - 1);// remove last element of inner list

        // join remaining items with comma [ as string ]
        String result = o.stream().reduce( (a, b) -> a + ", " + b).get();
        System.out.println(result); // Print out the result of each row
        return result; 
    }).collect(Collectors.joining("\n")); // return result - should you need it;
}

If you'd replace the Looping part with a call to printData(lists);, and also add the Method to your Program... You may get what you intended...
Otherwise, you could just directly replace the Looping Construct for(...){...}, with this functional equivalent like so:
    lists.stream().forEach( o -> {
        o.remove(o.size() - 1);
        System.out.println( o.stream().reduce( (a, b) -> a + ", " + b).get() );
    });

